# Delete all the name pipe instance ? in a pc c#

Tags: named-pipes

I'm getting following error when i try to open a another connection in name pipe

> System.IO.IOException was unhandled   HResult=-2147024665
>   Message=All pipe instances are busy.

how can I remove all pipe instance?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a pipe instance, any process which is holding a handle to the instance must either call CloseHandle on it, or the process must exit.

Is it your code which is acting as the pipe server? Are you setting the limit on the number of pipe instances correctly when you open the first handle to the pipe?

Post your code for both the pipe server and whatever code is "attempting to open another connection".